# Anchor embedded CSS (Open in new tab) does not work

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add embedded css in order to open all links in new tab and but it doesn't work:

```
<style type="text/css">
a
{
target-name: new;
 target-new : tab; 

}
</style>
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com" >Google </a>
</a>
</body>
```

I want to open link in new tab and I don't want to use 'target' property for each link.

Comment: Shouldn't you replace `<script type="text/css">` whith `<style type="text/css">`?

Comment: @PedramBehroozi - Thanks, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all guys for their comments and answers the following JQuery code fixed my problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").each(function()
 {
  $(this).attr("target","_blank");
  });
});
</script>
```

ref: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/open-external-links-in-new-window/

Answer (score 5):

Neither the target-name or target-new CSS properties will work. They were proposed by the CSS3 spec, but are not supported by any major browser. You'll have to rely on using the target="" attribute of the anchor tag instead or use JavaScript if you need something more dynamic.

Comment: Yes, he/she's right. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_target-name.asp)

Comment: You mean here? http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-hyperlinks I hope they kill it off then. CSS isn't meant for this stuff.

Comment: so, how we can open all links in new tabs?

Comment: You need to add the `target` attribute to all links you want to open in a new tab like this: `<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>`

Comment: @scumah - I know what the 'target' property does, but I need a solution for all links without any properties. This is what I've commented in chovy answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I usually apply rel=external attribute and use javascript to open a new window for external links:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" rel="external">Yahoo</a><br />
<a href="#">Internal</a>

$('a[rel=external]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(this.href, '_blank');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/CtLtv/

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to add any properties like 'rel' or 'target' to links.